# create custom gridview template fields for a List<>

Tags: asp.net, list, gridview

I have a List of Lists of string . I want to show it to user using a gridview . as number of columns are not known I decided to create gridview fields dynamically . I found some [tutorials](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13462/How-to-create-template-columns-dynamically-in-a-gr) but all of them use DataTable . I tried to use the same but I have problem with databinding event's "_columnName" :

```
    void field_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox txtdata = (TextBox)sender;

        GridViewRow container = (GridViewRow)txtdata.NamingContainer;

        object dataValue = DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, _columnName);

        if (dataValue != DBNull.Value)
        {
            txtdata.Text = dataValue.ToString();
        }

    }
```

as there is no column in list . any suggestion is appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much easier way would be  to set `AutoGenerateColumns` to true and use a `DataTable` as DataSource.

For example ( the aspx can be an empty GridView ):

```
List<List<String>> data = new List<List<String>>() { 
    new List<String>(){"Row1_Col1", "Row1_Col2",  "Row1_Col3"},
    new List<String>(){"Row2_Col1", "Row2_Col2",  "Row2_Col3"},
    new List<String>(){"Row3_Col1", "Row3_Col2",  "Row3_Col3"},
    new List<String>(){"Row4_Col1", "Row4_Col2",  "Row4_Col3"},
    new List<String>(){"Row5_Col1", "Row5_Col2",  "Row5_Col3"},
};
var tbl = new DataTable();
int maxFieldCount = data.Max(l => l.Count);
for (int i = 1; i <= maxFieldCount; i++)
    tbl.Columns.Add("Column" + i);
foreach (var list in data)
{
    DataRow newRow = tbl.Rows.Add();
    newRow.ItemArray = list.ToArray();
}
```

now it can be used  as DataSource of the `GridView`:

```
GridView1.DataSource = tbl;
GridView1.DataBind();
```